# Direct link to MiKTeX 2.9.5505

Tags: miktex

Where can I directly download the latest version 2.9.5505 of MiKTeX?
The main page does not have the latest version but you can upgrade it.

Comment: The net installers (setup-XXX.exe) downloads and installs a current, up-to-date miktex. The prepacked versions (basic-XXX and miktex-portable) are older and you should run the update manager after the installation .

Answer (score 3):

Also on CTAN the latest setup version seems to be 2.9.5105. Directory [CTAN:systems/win32/miktex/setup/](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup) contains:

```
ba­sic-mik­tex-2.9.5105-x64.exe   166174984   2014-01-01 19:08  
ba­sic-mik­tex-2.9.5105.exe       171108104   2014-01-01 19:08  
mik­tex-portable-2.9.5105.exe    164409038   2014-01-01 19:34
```

and the older versions

```
setup-2.9.4503-x64.exe            9728000   2012-04-30 20:59    
setup-2.9.4503.exe                7360000   2012-04-30 20:56
```

Since the basic programs does not change quite often in comparison to the magnitude of supported packages, it is not a surprise that the setup versions
does not cover each revision. It costs some effort to generate the setup files and upload them to the different locations (homepage, CTAN).

Comment: I'm asking because MiKTeX 2.9.5505 has all free Adobe fonts and I don't need to install individually every package I use. Hopefully someone will upload it.

Comment: @vejn The packages of MiKTeX can be downloaded from [CTAN:systems/win32/miktex/packages/tm/](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages). The packages are `.tar.lzma` files, which can be unpacked with 7-Zip, for example.